# How to know duration in site

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a .net web site(eg: www.mysite,com) and I use some external links in my site that redirect to other sites (like www.google.com). But how I know a user spend time in second site(ie www.google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no control over the external website - you cannot.

You cannot inject your own client-side scripting into external website (well, sometimes you can, but it's XSS and it's bad).

Google Analytics tracks the activity of the users on a certain website because website owner included javascript code.

It may be possible for Google to track user's activity over multiple websites but only if those website display Google Ads. It is not bullet-proof since users can block ads.

Comment: Yes Jakub with pleasure, but I am still searching any other methods that solve this issue.